# What is the function of the "mov eax, cr3; mov cr3, eax" in x86 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm disassembling a bit of code and I came across:

```
mov eax, cr3
mov cr3, eax
```

What is the function of those lines?

This is x86 low-level (bios/firmware/before boot loader) initialization code.  We haven't even setup up caches yet.

Comment: I think there's a more technical term than 'pleasuring' cr3, but it looks like that's all it's doing, yes.

Comment: +1 - it's an interesting question.

Comment: I don't think [edited for content] is a valid edit. Maybe rephrasing the sentence would be apt? Especially as the majority of SO users (I'm willing to bet) wouldn't mind the original phrasing.

Comment: If someone else wants to change my edit they are free to do so. And no, that language would not fly with the majority of SO users.

Comment: I'm usually not one for personal attacks, but such a prude at 25? Lighten up!

Comment: Those that want the original wording can look at the edit history. I actually like the "[edited for content]" since my first thought was not the (relatively) mild word that it actually was. And I'm pretty sure you don't do that to something else (like CR3), only to yourself :-)

Comment: I am a professional and conduct myself as one in public settings such as this. In addition, SO has a strict policy on offensive content, and as a member of the community with a high enough reputation to edit/semi-moderate, I consider it my responsibility to help keep the community clean. Many others on here in my position also feel the same way.

Comment: I'm not saying your reasons for editing were wrong, I'm saying your edit could have been more useful. I'm also saying you should stop worrying so much and be happy. But alas this is not the place for this discussion, so I'll stop hitting F5.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm mostly in a bad mood tonight because of WPF, haha. Seriously, though, if anyone wants to change my edit, be my guest, I won't change it back.

Comment: Well I can certainly relate to that!

Comment: "    Rollback to Revision 1 - Wrong part censored. Assembly code does more harm to kids than masturbation."  Oh the lulz.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is flushing the TLBs (Translation Lookaside Buffers) by loading cr3 with itself.

Intel even mentions the code in their "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Develoment Manual Volume 3A - System Programming Guide".

```
mov EAX,CR3  ; invalidate the TLB
mov CR3,EAX  ; by copying CR3 to itself
```

You can find that and many more handy manuals at:

http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/index.htm

Comment: What's the difference by doing directly "mov cr3, cr3"?

Comment: @Eliseo - That's not a legal instruction.  There are distinct "Load from register into control register" and "Load control register into register" instructions.  There is no control register -> control register mov instruction.